# Why is my if statement not working in some cases in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a cookie clicker game with only HTML CSS and JavaScript. I have different upgrades, but they dont hide correctly when you don't have enough cookies for it. Let me show the code (besides my css of course because that is unnecessary) and I will explain:

JS:

```
var num = 0;

var cookie = document.getElementById("cookie");
var incrementNum = 1;

function cookieClick() { 
    num += incrementNum;

    var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
    numbers.innerHTML = num + " Cookies";
    if (num >= 15){
        document.getElementById("cursor").style.display = "block";
    }
    if (num >= 100){
        document.getElementById("grandma").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function addCursor(){
    var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
    incrementNum = incrementNum + 1; 
    num = num - 15;
    numbers.innerHTML = num+" Cookies";

    if (num >= 15){
        cursor.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        cursor.style.display = "none";
    }
}  

function addGrandma(){
    var grandma = document.getElementById("grandma");
    incrementNum = incrementNum + 3; 
    num = num - 100;
    numbers.innerHTML = num+" Cookies";

    if (num >= 100){
        grandma.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        grandma.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id = "numbers"> </div>
    <div id = "cookie" onclick="cookieClick()">
        <img src="cookie.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

      <button id="cursor" onclick="addCursor()" style="display:none;">Add cursor - 15 cookies - +1 cookie per click</button><br>
      <button id="grandma" onclick="addGrandma()" style="display:none;">Add grandma - 100 cookies - +3 cookies per click</button><br>
  </div>
```

If I save up enough for a grandma, and buy one, the cursor button won't hide even when I have less than 15 cookies.

Comment: seems like you forgot the part where you explain. please specify what exactly you've tried and is not working. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @F.H. I added the explaining part. Yes sorry I forgot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand that the 'cursor' button should be shown only when num >= 15 and the 'grandma' button only when num >= 100. Because addCursor and addGrandma both reduce num, each may have impact on the visibility of both buttons. You must check for visibility of both buttons in both functions. You could introduce a shared function 'hideIfNecessary' for this purpose, as follows:

```
function hideIfNecessary() {
    var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
    var grandma = document.getElementById("grandma");

    if (num < 15) {
        cursor.style.display = "none";  
    }
    if (num < 100) {
        grandma.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function addCursor(){
    incrementNum = incrementNum + 1; 
    num = num - 15;
    numbers.innerHTML = num+" Cookies";

    hideIfNecessary();
}  

function addGrandma(){
    incrementNum = incrementNum + 3; 
    num = num - 100;
    numbers.innerHTML = num+" Cookies";

    hideIfNecessary();
}
```